# MYSQL subtracting in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a simple subtraction work in the WHERE clause, I have the following:

```
SELECT account, SUM(payments) AS total_payments, amount_due FROM clients
LEFT JOIN payments ON clients.id = payments.id
LEFT JOIN account_details ON clients.id = account_details.id
WHERE account_details.amount_due - SUM(payments) < 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, `WHERE` is evaluated before the `SELECT`... You need `HAVING`

Comment: Additionally to @Kermit: using account_details.amount_due otherwise than in a join condition will change your outer joins implicitly to inner joins, because this column may not be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use SUM in a where cause.
Try this:

```
SELECT account, SUM(payments) AS total_payments, amount_due FROM clients
LEFT JOIN payments ON clients.id = payments.id
LEFT JOIN account_details ON clients.id = account_details.id
GROUP BY account
HAVING SUM(payments) < 0;
```

Comment: it has to be `GROUP BY ... HAVING ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, but anyway it is not optimal query.

```
SELECT a.* from 

 (SELECT account, SUM(payments) AS total_payments, amount_due FROM clients 
 LEFT JOIN payments ON clients.id = payments.id)as a

LEFT JOIN account_details ON clients.id = account_details.id
WHERE account_details.amount_due - a.total_payments < 0
```